# Spring gradle build jar cannot find main class with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, gradle, jar

I build jar file in spring framework test code with gradle.

and I run jar file "java -jar jarFile.jar"
but it can't run with some error code.

I checked Main-Class attributes in spring project's build.gradle file 
And MANIFEST.FM file in jar file

this is my Main class java Code

```
package com.apress.springrecipes.sequence;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.apress.springrecipes.sequence.config.SequenceConfiguration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SequenceConfiguration.class);

        SequenceGenerator generator = context.getBean(SequenceGenerator.class);

        System.out.println(generator.getSequence());
        System.out.println(generator.getSequence());
    }
}
```

and this is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "com.apress.springrecipes.sequence.Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = "${rootProject.name}"
    version =  "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
    manifest {
        attributes "Implementation-Title": "${rootProject.name}",
                   "Implementation-Version": version,
                   "Main-Class": "${mainClassName}"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    springVersion = '4.2.0.RELEASE'
}

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"
}
```

this is MANIFEST.FM file in jar file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: recipe_2_2
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Main-Class: com.apress.springrecipes.shop.Main
```

when i run jar file i get error message

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

how can i fix it ?

Comment: Could you post `Main` class code?

Comment: @JonathanJohx I post it  !

Comment: Looks like you built from other Main class, so please make sure you run in Main class in order to create a new jar

Answer (score 0):

the gradle 'application' plugin will output the zip file in **build/distributions**, so you can extract into a folder, it have **bin/, lib/**

you can run your program just like

```
bin/${rootProject.name}
```

please don't run your jar file in the lib directly